# Displaying HTML carrots without it being treated as HTML with DJango

Tags: python, django

I am working with a Django project and right now I am building my HTML table inside of my view and this displaying it on my html template. Some of the data that is in my table looks like `<word>`. The issue is when it gets displayed it is treating those carrots as HTML code and this the word is not being displayed. I am displaying my table like:

```
{% autoescape off %}
    {{table}}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Any way to make sure the carrots get displayed correctly?

Comment: Remove the `{% autoescape off %}` and `{% endautoescape %}`. This will then escape the HTML such that `<word>` is converted to `&lt;word&gt;`.

Comment: If I do this, then my entire table is displayed as text on the page.

Comment: If that variable `table` is supposed to have HTML in it, then `<word>` should _already_ be escaped to `&lt;word&gt;` in it, otherwise how would one find what you want to escape in that and what you don't?

Comment: @halloween1: wel you will either have to escape the items then *before*, or store your table in another way, such that the Django template engine will produce the `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<td>` tags, etc.

Comment: I just did a string replace and it is printing correctly now.